# cakePHP unique email username

Tags: cakephp

I just need a bit of help with identifying the email of the user which is also the username in the database, I used the 'isUnique' in the model but for some reason it is not giving an error message and it still registers the user please can someone give me a bit of help here is the code...

**MODEL**

```
App::uses('AuthComponent','Controller/Component');
class User extends AppModel {

     public $validate = array(
        'email' => 'email',
        'email' => array(
        'required' => array(
        'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        'message' => 'Please enter a valid email address for username',
        'unique' => array(
        'rule' => 'isUnique',
        'message' => 'Please enter another email, this one is already taken'
       )
       )
       ),
        'password' => array(
        'required'=> array(
        'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        'message' => 'Please enter a valid password',

        'rule' => array('minLength','8'),
        'message' => 'Please enter minimum 8 characters'
       )
       )
    );

       public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] =   AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
        }
          return true;
    }


 }
**CONTROLLER**

<?php


class usersController extends AppController
{
    public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('add');
}
    var $name = 'Users';




    public function add()
     {

    if (!empty($this ->data))
    {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->data))
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Thank you for registering');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        else
        {
            // Make the password fields blank
            unset($this->data['User']['password']);
            unset($this->data['User']['confirm_password']);

            $this->Session->setFlash('An error occurred, try again!');
        }
    }


}

    function index()
    {

    }
    public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
      }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<h2>End a problem registration</h2>
        <p>Please fill out details to register</p>

<?php
        echo $this->Form->Create('User',array('action' => 'add'));
        echo $this->Form->input('title');
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
        echo $this->Form->input('surname');
        echo $this->Form->input('email');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
        echo $this->Form->end('Register');
```

Comment: Mind your casings, usersController should be UsersController, but -Form->create() is a method should be lowercase. You should also clean up your code - or write cleaner code. It is hard to follow. Also: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Your array declarations for your validation rules are wrong.
They have the wrong "level", thus making them invalid.
E.g. email key is used twice.

Please correct them according to the documentation - and using correct 1 tab indentation.
This will make them both correct and readable and easily prevents the mistake you made above.